# Applying easing to setTimeout delays, within a loop

Tags: javascript

I am calling multiple setTimeout's within a javascript loop.  The delay is currently set to increase by 200ms upon every iteration making the 'self.turnpages()' function fire every 200ms.

However I would like to apply some sort of easing to these variable delays so that as the loop begins to reach the last few iterations the delay gets further apart causing the function firing to slow down.

```
var self = this;    
var time = 0; 

for( var i = hide, len = diff; i < len; i++ ) {
                     (function(s){
                             setTimeout(function(){                    
                                        self.turnPages(s);                           
                             }, time);
                       })(i);                                  
             time = (time+200);
}
```

I am at a complete loss how to start with this.

Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Instead of 200 being a constant, it should be a function of "i".

Comment: @Pointy - Indeed, however, I have no idea where to begin with the math involved to achieve what I require.

Comment: Well it depends on what you want the easing curve to look like I guess.

Comment: A simple Easeinoutquad would be perfect

Comment: @nnnnnn 'hide' is the starting point i.e the current page and 'diff' is the page we want to turn to.  I am animating page turns on a canvas element and wish to be able to turn from any page to another while animating the pageflips of all pages inbetween.

Comment: Downmodded as variable names are specific - this isn't helpful for others to learn as we have to work out what `s` and `i` and `diff` are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like a job for Robert Penner's easing equations! You can download the original ActionScript 2.0 versions [here](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/) (just remove the strong-typing on the parameters to port to JavaScript) and there's a good explanation of the parameters [here](http://upshots.org/actionscript/jsas-understanding-easing).

Something like the following will do what you want ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GQMq/3/)):

```
var time = 0;
var diff = 30;

var minTime = 0;
var maxTime = 1000;

// http://upshots.org/actionscript/jsas-understanding-easing
/*
    @t is the current time (or position) of the tween. This can be seconds or frames, steps, seconds, ms, whatever – as long as the unit is the same as is used for the total time [3].
    @b is the beginning value of the property.
    @c is the change between the beginning and destination value of the property.
    @d is the total time of the tween.
*/
function easeInOutQuad(t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t /= d / 2) < 1) return c / 2 * t * t + b;
  return -c / 2 * ((--t) * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
}

function easeOutQuad(t, b, c, d) {
  return -c * (t /= d) * (t - 2) + b;
}

function easeInQuad(t, b, c, d) {
  return c * (t /= d) * t + b;
}

for (var i = 0, len = diff; i <= len; i++) {
  (function(s) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      //self.turnPages(s);                           
      console.log("Page " + s + " turned");
    }, time);
  })(i);

  time = easeInOutQuad(i, minTime, maxTime, diff);
  console.log(time);
}
```

Comment: absolutely perfect.  Thank you

Comment: No problem gordyr, happy easing!

Answer (score 3):

**2019 answer**: You don't need to make your own loop timings, or deal with single character variables, just to run functions with easing. Here's a quick example using [`easy-ease`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-ease) from npm:

```
import ease from 'easy-ease';

ease({
  startValue: 1,
  endValue: 33,
  durationMs: 2000,
  onStep: function(value) {
    console.log(value)
  }
});
```

Comment: It's worth. to add, that the performance of this library is really pure. If you have more than 20 elements to render with start 0, end 100, be sure that this library has only few frames per second.

Comment: @kris_iv Do you mean 'pure' or 'poor'?

Comment: OK. Yes, if you're animating 20 elements I'd use a CSS easing rather than JS. But there are many other uses for easing asides from animation.