# Applying easing to a loop delay

Tags: loops, go, delay, easing

To speak simple, I am trying to figure out how to apply easing to a loop delay.

```
for (i := 0; i < 114; i++) {
    // do a task
    time.Sleep(//delay before next job)
}
```

As you can read it, this is very basic. Let say I want to complete the whole loop in 3s (job completion time is negligeable, `t <= us`). What is the proper method with Penner's Equations to calculate for each iteration the proper eased delay ?

So, with this function, to simulate an acceleration from zero-velocity, how should I use the `t` parameter each iteration of the loop to create the proper delay to sleep for ?

```
func easeInQuad(t float64) {
  return math.Pow(t, 2)
}
```

I would be very thankfull if you could help me about this. Equations has not been a problem so far, but how to use them with my use case instead.

My question could looks like this one at first : [Applying easing to setTimeout delays, within a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081547/applying-easing-to-settimeout-delays-within-a-loop)
but this one does not take the total time of the loop in account.

However, I think it may be better to use equations rewritten to use only one parameter, in range [0,1] : https://gist.github.com/rezoner/713615dabedb59a15470

From my understanding, I have to calculate the abstract "percentage time elapsed", and somehow interpolate this value with an easing function.

This Node project seems to do just that : https://github.com/CharlotteGore/animation-timer, but again I can't figure out how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penner's Equations fundamentally require two parameters: the current progress, and the total possible progress.  Alternatively, however, you can instead provide it with percentage-of-total-progress as a single parameter (as a value between 0 and 1), since that's what it uses the current and total to calculate anyway.

Using your original code, if you want 114 iterations to take place within 3 seconds, the easiest way is to use your iteration index as the current progress, and 114 as the total, then multiply the calculated delay factor by your total duration 3.0s.

Note, Penner's Equations calculate total displacement from start position, NOT relative displacement for each step, so you actually need to calculate that difference yourself.  Thus the delay for *this* iteration is the total displacement (delay) for this iteration minus the total displacement for the last iteration:

```
func DoStuffWithEasing() {
    iterations := 114
    runTime := 3 * time.Second

    for i := 1; i <= iterations; i++ {
        // do a task
        time.Sleep(easeInQuadDelay(i, iterations, runTime))
    }
}

func easeInQuadDelay(c, t int, dur time.Duration) time.Duration {
    if c <= 0 || t == 0 { // invalid cases
        return 0
    }

    // This return can be a single-liner, but I split it up for clarity
    // Note that time.Durations are fundamentally int64s,
    // so we can easily type convert them to float64s and back

    this := math.Pow(float64(c)/float64(t), 2)
    last := math.Pow(float64(c-1)/float64(t), 2)
    return time.Duration((this - last) * float64(dur))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/TTgZUYUvxW

[Graph of the easing](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+3*%28x%2F114%29%5E2+from+0+to+114)

Comment: Whoo, thanks a bunch, you made it so clear. So to use another easing function, i have to change how is calculated `this` and `last` with the same parameter ?

Comment: Exactly.  Incidentally, you can even do it dynamically with a bit of functional programming, if you want.  Example: https://play.golang.org/p/JQCIOWwxEs

Comment: Alright. Lasth thing, i suspect this is due to how you compute delay, but according to the graph of the `inOutQuad` equation (http://easings.net/fr#easeInOutQuad), the delay should decrease-increase-decrease instead of increase-stagnate at frame 57-58-decrease.

Comment: EDIT: I meant this to reproduce the effect of acceleration/deceleration, because otherwise it reflect the graph.

Comment: Technically, the `delay()` function is calculating a sort of poor-man's derivative of that graph.  It's returning the *change* in the graph from the last iteration to the current one.  It should start at zero, increase to some value, then decrease back to zero.  Since the quad equation is quadratic, the derivative should be linear, but InOut is piecewise, meaning the derivative is piecewise too.  **Edit:** broken link.  Paste this into http://www.wolframalpha.com: `Plot[Piecewise[{{y=2*(x/114)^2,x<=57},{y=(x/114)*(4-2(x/114))-1, x >= 57}}], {x, 0, 114}]`

Comment: Basically, it *is* reproducing acceleration and deceleration.  The total delay reflects your easing graph properly.  The key is that that graph is showing the *total delay so far*, _NOT_ the delay since the last iteration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120835/discussion-between-william-poussier-and-kaedys).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use time.Ticker.

```
numLoops := 144
timePerIteration := time.Duration(3) * time.Second / time.Duration(numLoops)
ticker := time.NewTicker(timePerIteration)
for i := 0; i < numLoops; i++ {
    // your code
    <-ticker.C
}
ticker.Stop()
```

Comment: Using ticker or timer isn't the question, but how to implement the return of a penner's easing equation instead.